# Rails 6 - tests failing due to ActionPack .empty? for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-6

I've recently upgraded my rails app from 6.0.0.beta3 to 6.0.0 and all my tests that use a route either `_path` or `_url` I get the following error:

```
HomeControllerTest#test_should_see_home_page:
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
    /.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:781:in `optimize_routes_generation?'
    /.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:220:in `optimize_routes_generation?'
    /.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:228:in `optimize_routes_generation?'
    /.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:198:in `call'
    /.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:329:in `block in define_url_helper'
    /.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:404:in `public_send'
    /.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:404:in `method_missing'
    /code/events/test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:HomeControllerTest>'
```

Has anyone see this before? Maybe I've missed a configuration during the upgrade? My application works fine in a browser, it's the tests that seem affected.

**EDIT**

The command I'm running is:

```
BACKTRACE=YES rails test test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb
```

And the test is very simple, which always fail on the route line:

```
require 'test_helper'

class HomeControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should see home page" do
    get root_path
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I've finally found the issue. In my environment.rb file I am doing the following

```
App::Application.default_url_options = App::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

as they both use the same settings. I'm doing this as I'm using the route helpers in my models (XX_path / XX_url). I wasn't setting the `action_mailer.default_url_options` in my `environment/test.rb` file and this is why my routes were breaking. Now I check if the `env` is in test mode before assigning the `App::Application.default_url_options` as the tests automatically use **http://www.example.com** as the url options.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run single spec file instead all - sometimes the error message is confusing if we do not run a specific test

Comment: thanks. I've tried this and still shows the error. I've updated my question above with more details of the test and command I'm running.

Comment: If I change the route line to `get "/"` it will work but because my views have routes via multiple `link_to` calls the test will fail with the same error mentioned above. I have no idea why my routes aren't loading in my tests.